# comparing class length of multilabelbinarizer

Tags: pandas, data-mining

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer



DATA_FILE= pd.read_csv("data.csv")
Itemsets=DATA_FILE.groupby(['order_id'])[ 'product_id'].apply(list)
arr=Itemsets.to_numpy()




mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mat=mlb.fit_transform(arr)


final=pd.DataFrame(mat,columns=mlb.classes_)
```

I am working with a CSV file the looks a bit like this:

```
order_id,product_id
110,Organic Lemon
110,Organic Unsweetened Almond Milk
110,Beef Top Round Steak
110,Cotija
110,"Organic Red Radish, Bunch"
110,Banana
110,Organic Iceberg Lettuce
110,Red Vine Tomato
110,Jalapeno Peppers
110,B 12 Liquid B Complex
150,Tesora Medium Roast
150,Dark Chocolate Nuts & Sea Salt Bars
150,Organic Raisin Bran Cereal
373,Original Thin Sausage & Pepperoni Pizza
373,Mexican Style Taco Shredded Cheese
373,Original Thin Pepperoni Pizza
373,Classic Wheat Bread
373,Black Beans
373,Original Kettle Cooked Potato Chips
373,Large Burrito Flour Tortillas
373,Swanson Premium Chicken Breast Chunks
429,Coppertop AA Batteries
429,Gel Hand Wash Refill Sweet Water
429,"Concentrated Bleach, Regular"
429,Free & Clear Natural Laundry Detergent For Sensitive Skin
429,Onion Powder
429,Magic Eraser Cleaning Sponge 2ct. Surface Care
429,All in 1 Powerball Fresh Scent Automatic Dishwasher Detergent
429,Sprouted Organic Cinnamon Raisin English Muffins
429,Zucchini Noodles
429,Butternut Squash Noodles
429,Shaved Brussel Sprouts
429,French Lavender All-Purpose Natural Surface Cleaner
429,Bathroom Cleaner Natural Tub + Tile Cleaner
```

I am trying to create an itemset matrix where each cell encodes whether an item is in an itemset or not.

I attempted to check the length of arr after removing duplicates (which to my knowledge should be the same as the number of columns as the itemset matrix or just the number of classes in the final dataframe):

```
for item in arr:
    if item not in list_without_duplicates:
        list_without_duplicates.append(item)

print(len(list_without_duplicates))
```

I compared this with `print(len(mlb.classes_))` but found that they were not the same. What am I doing wrong?